# How can I update data in a parent object from inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat set up like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="obj in objs | orderBy: 'number'">                             
   <button data-ng-click="AddTopic(obj, Id);">
      Add Topic
   </button>
</div>
```

In my controller

```
$scope.AddTopic = function (obj, Id) {
   $http.get('/api/GetSubTopic?Id=' + Id)
                .success(function (data) {
                    obj.subTopics.push(data);
   });
};
```

When the user clicks on the button it gets the topic information and adds it to the obj.subTopics array.

However this seems not to update the data in the objs object. How can I make it update that data?

Comment: `obj` is a reference, if some changes have been made via `obj`, the same object in `objs` should be updated too. You should show more of your controller code, and what is `objs`?

Comment: Where do you get `Id`. in `AddTopic(obj,Id)` And also you can lose the semicolon.

Comment: The Id comes from a select box. It's giving the correct Id and the call is coming back correctly so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: Cool, my answer below should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably updating the references but the problem is that the `$digest` isn't being triggered. Since you're already doing an asynchronous call you can simply use the promise that `$http` returns That looks like this:

```
$scope.AddTopic = function (obj, Id) {
   $http.get('/api/GetSubTopic?Id=' + Id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    obj.subTopics.push(response.data);
   });
};
```

It is very similar.

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfQEBdSz7hkxuWRvMkpV). I use `$q` to emulate the async call. But they're all angular promises, which are special because the cause a `$digest` to occur.